# I am unable to properly align my TicTacToe items in my CSS grid, borders get messed up

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My TicTacToe grid is fine without `justify-items:center;` and `align-items:center;` (the items are not centered as I want, but my grid is OK).

But I want to center my items so the 'X' is right in the middle of the square so I add `justify-items:center;` and `align-items:center;` to my CSS grid, but when I do that my grid just gets weird, the borders gets messed up.

So how do I properly align my grid without messing with the borders?

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 100px 100px 100px / 100px 100px 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TicTacToe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>A Tic-Tac-Toe game</h1>

  <div id="container">
    <a href="#" class="item" id="1">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="2">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="3">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="4">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="5">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="6">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="7">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="8">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="9">X</a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you apply the centering properties to the grid container, that centers the *grid item*. That's what you're seeing. You actually want to center the *content of the grid item*, so apply the centering properties to the item, not the container. https://jsfiddle.net/csvg2f12/

Answer (score 0):

Just added 
    text-align: -webkit-center; and removed two other classes.

hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 100px 100px 100px / 100px 100px 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  /*justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;  -- not needed */
 text-align: -webkit-center;
}

.item {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TicTacToe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>A Tic-Tac-Toe game</h1>

  <div id="container">
    <a href="#" class="item" id="1">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="2">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="3">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="4">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="5">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="6">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="7">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="8">X</a>
    <a href="#" class="item" id="9">X</a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are applying `justify-content: center` & `align-items: center` in the wrong place.  You want that applied to the `.item` class.  Applying those to the `#container` will center ***the entire grid area*** but not the contents inside each grid cell. The solution below is one way to achieve what you are after.

Applying `text-align: center` to the grid will center the text-content in each cell ***horizontally, but not vertically***.  It the grid-cell dimensions were to change to say `grid-template: 150px 150px 150px / 400px 400px 400px;` you will see that the below approach will make sure the text-content is always centered appropriately.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;  
  grid-template: 100px 100px 100px / 100px 100px 100px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>A Tic-Tac-Toe game</h1>    

<div id="container">
  <a href="#" class="item" id="1">X</a>
  <a href="#" class="item" id="2">X</a>    
  <a href="#" class="item" id="3">X</a>
  <a href="#" class="item" id="4">X</a>   
  <a href="#" class="item" id="5">X</a>
  <a href="#" class="item" id="6">X</a>                   
  <a href="#" class="item" id="7">X</a>
  <a href="#" class="item" id="8">X</a>
  <a href="#" class="item" id="9">X</a>
</div>
```